# How to calculate dimensions for different sw-xxx dp structure

Tags: android, android-layout

Previously we follow the 
**ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi** .... structure.

In this structure easy to calculate for all dimensions values. with following

36x36 **(0.75x)** for low-density

48x48 **(1.0x baseline)** for medium-density

72x72 **(1.5x)** for high-density

96x96 **(2.0x)** for extra-high-density

144x144 **(3.0x)** for extra-extra-high-density

192x192 **(4.0x)** for extra-extra-extra-high-density

But current project onwards we move to **sw-320dp sw-420dp,sw-600dp,sw-720dp,sw-800dp**

**My problem:**

I searched in Official document & also stackoverflow no calculation available for sw-XXXdp structure.

How to calculate the dimension values for different sw-XXXdp dimension files?

Anybody give clue or some ideas for this structure. thanks for your valuable answers.

Comment: what exactly do you want to calculate?

Comment: @pskink In previous structure we only design for mdpi. and then we calculate for other dimensions. for ex In mdpi image height 100dp means we give 150dp for hdpi. How we calculate same like that in sw-XXXdp structure?

Comment: sorry, i have no idea what you are talking about